# waking up ios applications without using ios notification

Tags: ios, notifications

Is it possible to wake up a background application with a non ios notification center? e.g. if I were creating a calling or messaging application is it possible to wake the application via SMS.

Comment: Even if this were possible I'd have to say don't do it. It would be incredibly annoying to get kicked out of a game, or what ever you were doing because reading a new message was forced upon you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. If you want to call app outside the device, you should use APNS. On the device you can use local notification. Sending SMS to wake up app is kinda wrong. People don't like such solutions - imagine bunch of SMS every day for different apps. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you have background code running, you can schedule a local notification to yourself. If the user clicks "Ok" then you will come to the foreground. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW31) for a description and sample code.

As far as I can tell, the only ways to launch an app without user input is via a custom URL handler or via an accessory. It doesn't sound like an accessory fits your use case. Sadly you can't open URLs from the background, so you can't use this to wake yourself.